# Derive the distribution of a lower censored s.v.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I could use some pointers solving this problem:

> Given a certain s.v. $X$ with cdf $F_x(x)$ and pdf $f_X(x)$. Let s.v. $Y$ be the lower censored of $X$ at $x=b$. Meaning:
>
> $$Y = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if }X<b\\
> X & \text{if } X \geq b\end{cases}$$
>
> Find cdf $F_Y(y)$ and pdf $f_Y(y)$

#### My attempt

I'm looking for 
$$\begin{align}
F_Y(y) = \mathcal{P}(Y<y) &= \mathcal{P}(Y<y\mid X<b)\mathcal{P}(X<b)+\mathcal{P}(Y<y\mid X \geq b)\mathcal{P}(X\geq b)\\
& = \mathcal{P}(0<y\mid X<b)\mathcal{P}(X<b) + \mathcal{P}(X<y\mid X \geq b)\mathcal{P}(X\geq b) 
\end{align}$$

I've tried continuing using Bayes, but I always get kinda stuck. Which path should I follow?

Is the right mental picture for this problem?
[image: censored]

*Solution should be: $F_Y(y) = \frac{F_X(y)-F_X(b)}{1-F_X(b)}$*

Comment: Did you want to write that $Y=X$ if $X\geqslant b$ and $Y=0$ if $X<b$? As it is written now, the definition of Y doesn't make sense.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for noticing!

Comment: The model you have defined is that of a lower censored random variable --- this is NOT the same as "truncation" referred to in your title and question.

Comment: Also notice that $P(Y=0)\geq P(X<b)$. So if $P(X<b)>0$ then $P(Y=0)>0$. In that situation $Y$ has no PDF.

Comment: Your stated 'solution' is inconsistent with your definition of $Y$, as the latter has a discrete mass at the point $Y=0$ with $P(X<b)$. So, either your question is wrong, or your stated solution is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If Stefan is right (and I think so) then to find $F_Y(y):=P(Y\leq y)$ discern the cases:

If $0\leq y$ then:

$$Y\leq y\iff X<b\vee X\leq y$$
If $y<0$ then:

$$Y\leq y\iff b\leq X\leq y$$

---

**edit**:

If $b>0$ then we discern:

- $y<0$. Then $\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ b\leq X\leq y\right\} =\emptyset$
  so that $P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =0$
- $0\leq y<b$. Then $\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ X<b\vee X\leq y\right\} =\left\{ X<b\right\} $
  so that $P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =P\left\{ X<b\right\} $
- $y\geq b$. Then $\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ X<b\vee X\leq y\right\} =\left\{ X\leq y\right\} $
  so that $P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =P\left\{ X\leq y\right\} $

If $b\leq0$ then we discern:

- $y<b$. Then $\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ b\leq X\leq y\right\} =\emptyset$
  so that $P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =0$
- $b\leq y<0$. Then $\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ b\leq X\leq y\right\} $
  so that $P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =P\left\{ b\leq X\leq y\right\} $
- $0\leq y$. Then $\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =\left\{ X<b\vee X\leq y\right\} =\left\{ X\leq y\right\} $
  so that $P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =P\left\{ X\leq y\right\} $

Comment: I don't really get your suggestion. Why does $Y\leq y$ imply $X< b\vee X\leq y$?

Comment: If $X<b\vee X\leq y$ is *not* true then $X\geq b\wedge X>y$. Then
from $X\geq b$ it follows that $Y=X$ and then from $X>y$ it follows that $Y>y$

Comment: OK, that seem reasonable. However I still experience problems with the problem. 1) How should I go on? (how do you combine both statements) $$\mathcal{P}(X<b \vee X \leq y)$$ 2) How did you find the cases? $0\leq y, y<0$? I would think the cases $y<b, y\geq b$ would make more sense? (I believe I'm thinking about this problem the wrong way, is the mental picture i've added correct?)

Comment: In your picture $b$ is positive. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: no, it's just a random choice, the sign of $b$ is not known.

Comment: Then I am afraid that also the case $b\leq 0$ and $b>0$ must be treated separately.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you were dealing with the constrained random variable $X|X>b.$ If that were the case, then the probability density function is  $$f(x|x>b)={{f(x)} \over {Pr[X>b]}},$$ where $x>b.$ Integrating this with $b$ as the lower limit gives the cumulative distribution function $$F(x|x>b)={{F(x)-F(b)} \over {1-F(b)}}$$ Now you have indicated that this is the intended solution. So perhaps your problem definition is inaccurate.

Comment: This is inconsistent with the definition of the OP's variable Y, which has a discrete mass at the point $Y = 0$.

Comment: Yes. So either the problem definition is incorrect or the given solution is incorrect. The OP can pinpoint the issue.